# Postgres: truncate / load causes basic queries to take seconds

Tags: postgresql, performance, bulk-load

I have a Postgres table that on a nightly basis gets truncated, and then reloaded in a bulk insert (a million or so records).

This table is behaving very strangely: basic queries such as "SELECT * from mytable LIMIT 10" are taking 40+ seconds. Records are narrow, just a couple integer columns.

Perplexed.. very much appreciate your advice.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59170/very-slow-execution-of-a-simple-query

Comment: `log_lock_waits` ? Or on newer PostgreSQL, `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`